# In char **function() , dynamic allocation of char array gives undesired result

Tags: c++

This is my C++ code .
According to me , it should give output:
abc
Garbage
abc
But it is giving output:
abc
Garbage
Garbage

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


char **func()
{
char* PA = new char[10];
PA[0]='a';
PA[1]='b';
PA[2]='c';
PA[3]='\0';

printf("%s\n",PA);
printf("Garbage\n");

char **PPA = &PA;
return PPA;

}

int main()
{
 printf("%s\n",*func());
 return 0;
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You return the address of the local variable `PA`.

Comment: returning local variable address is UB. Period.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648

Comment: returning an address of a local variable

Comment: After your suggestions, This is working  char **result = new char*();  *result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10000);  *(*result+0) = 'a'; *(*result+1) = 'b'; *(*result+2) = 'c'; *(*result+3) = '\0';

Answer (score 3):

```
char **PPA = &PA;
```

Retrieves the address of the variable `PA` itsself, which is an automatic variable and goes out of scope as soon as the function terminates. That means you have undefined behavior here. The C standard doesn't guarantee any consistent behavior, so anything may happen, including what you experienced.

To fix that, you could change the function prototype to `char* func()` and return `PA` directly and remove `PPA` altogether.

Comment: Or since this is supposed to be C++, use std::string

Comment: Agree with Peter - very much self-inflicted. C++ is object-oriented, C is pointer-oriented.